# ASP.NET SPA with VueJS: only serving certain routes/files based on authorization

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

**Progress:**

I have been making an ASP.NET Web API project with the SPA option where I serve a Vue.js application.

I have already set up authentication and authorization for the back-end API controllers, and thus one could login and request from certain endpoints iff authorized by role.

**Problem:**

A problem I am seeing (or maybe I am seeing this wrong), is that in production the client-app gets bundled and served to the user.
This application, as of now, also contains certain pages with database modification properties for admins. The controllers are set up well for this, nobody other than admins have access to these API endpoints.

However, in my client-app these pages contain forms with database structures (e.g. an add form), since the bundled js gets served, any user can see this page in the bundled js (right?), even if I add vue-router authorization.

**Question:**

My question therefore is, how can I serve only authorized parts of my clientapp to users with lower privelege, or should I take the approach of making multiple clientapps and add authorization on the back-end for serving these seperate bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, in my client-app these pages contain forms with database structures (e.g. an add form), since the bundled js gets served, any user can see this page in the bundled js

Yes but why is this a problem ? Assuming your forms are Vue components, whole template is compiled into Javascript. You can take a look at the production build bundle yourself and ask yourself whether you can gather any useful info just by reading it (and you know the source code!)

Just protect the vue-router routes with same role-based system you use for API (using [meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) for example) so no non-admin user can access the routes.

Plus you can make this routes [lazy loaded](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html). Which means the code rendering them will be downloaded by the browser only for admin users. This is a good idea anyway as your app will be smaller and faster for most users (assuming most users are not admins)

Comment: Thanks! Fair point you make, I will then probably just go for lazy loading with vue router meta-field.